# Exercise 1.64 of Megginson's "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory".

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Could someone verify whether my solution to the following exercise is correct? The reason I am a bit in doubt is because the chapter of which this Exercise is part consists of the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem and Closed Graph Theorem, so I would expect I have to use those theorems. However, I guess my direct approach works.

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T : X \to \ell^{\infty} (\mathbb{N})$ be a linear operator. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(Tx)_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ entry of $Tx$ and let $f_n$ be a linear functional on $X$ given by $x \mapsto (Tx)_n$. Prove that $T$ is bounded if and only if each $f_n$ is bounded.

My solution is the following:

> > Suppose $T$ is bounded. Then there exists a $M > 0$ such that $\| Tx \|_{\infty} \leq M \| x \|_X$ whenever $x \in X$. Therefore, it holds for all $x \in X$ that
> >     $$ |f_n(x)| = |(Tx)_n| \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |(Tx)_n| \leq M \|x\|_X, $$
> >     and hence $f_n$ is bounded.
> >
> > Suppose $f_n$ is bounded. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $M_n > 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M_n \| x \|_X$. Let 
> >     $$ K := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{|f_n (x)|}{\|x\|_X} $$
> >     Then, for all $x \in X$, 
> >     $$ \| Tx\|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f_n (x)| \leq K \| x \|_X ,$$
> >     and hence $T$ is bounded.

The next exercise is the same as the one above, but with $\ell^{\infty}$ replaced with $\ell^{1}$. I guess a similar approach works there?

Comment: You need to show that $K$ is finite and independent of $x$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did for the first part is correct.

For the converse, however, there is a problem. You have to prove that the sequence $\left(M_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded. Your $K$ depends on $X$, and the task is to prove that $K$ is finite.

You can solve the question using the uniform boundedness principle: since $Tx$ belongs to $\ell^\infty$ for each $x\in X$, we have that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|f_n(x)\right|\lt+\infty$.

Comment: I see now the problem with my original attempt, but unfortunately I do not entirely understand your argument. Saying that "$Tx$ belongs to $\ell^{\infty}$" means that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | (Tx)_n | = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | f_n (x) | < \infty$, doesn't it? I do not understand your implication. Could you please argue a bit more on this?

Comment: The principle of uniform boundedness shows that the linear functionals $f_n$ have a norm which is bounded independently on $n$, which is what you needed.

Comment: I think I understand it, but I just want to be entirely sure: Since $Tx \in \ell^{\infty}$ for $x \in X$, it holds for all $x \in X$ that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f_n(x)| < \infty$. As $f_n$ is bounded, it holds, by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, that $\sup_{x \in X} \| Tx \| = \sup_{x \in X} sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f_n(x)| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)| < \infty$, which implies that $T$ is bounded. Could you please confirm that this is correct?

Comment: It is almost correct: you have to restrict the suprema on $x$ to the $x$ of norm $1$, otherwise it is infinite except in the trivial case where $Tx=0$ for each $x$.